# C#- Getting ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED with Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I am trying to open a site which is on another network, I get:
and `ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED`
but when I try to add proxy for the browser I get following message `ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES`.
Below is how I am setting my proxy for the browser:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--proxy-server=http://user:pwd@myproxy.com:8080");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try desiredcapablities

Comment: Try without username and password, username and password are not supported in command line proxy